# Is there an efficient way to store Firebase data in an arraylist and then read it?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am trying to store my firebase data in an arraylist and then use it, but when I try to read the arraylist it shows null or only 2 data. Using the Log, I realize that the childEventListener is storing the data one by one and when I read the arraylist it doesn't have all the data. So I need to store all the data first and when the childEventListener finishes read the arraylist.

I need help finding the most efficient way to do this.

This is the code I have: (I have this code snippet written in onCreate).

```
ArrayList<Data> listData = new ArrayList<>();
/**onCreate**/
childEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {


            if (dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() > 0) {
                Data data = dataSnapshot.getValue(Data.class);
                listData.add(data);
                buildRecycler();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.AunNoHayDatos), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }


            
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    };

    mDbRef.addChildEventListener(childEventListener);
/**onCreate**/

/*out of onCreate*/
 public void buildRecycler(){
    
    
    for(int i=0; i< listData.size(); i++){
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
        Date date = null;
        try {
            date = df.parse(listData.get(i).getFecha());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        if(date != null){
            cal.setTime(date);
        }
        cal.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.SUNDAY);
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SUNDAY);

        String[] days = new String[7];
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
        {
            days[j] = df.format(cal.getTime());
            cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        }

        listWeeks.add(days[0]);
       
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easier in that case to use a `ValueEventListener` like this:

```
valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        listData.clear();
        for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Data data = childSnapshot.getValue(Data.class);
            listData.add(data);
        }
        buildRecycler();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException(); // never ignore errors
    }
};

mDbRef.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener);
```

So now all data is passed in a single `dataSnapshot`, and we loop over its `getChildren()` to get the individual `Data` objects.

You'll note that I added a `listData.clear()`, since `onDataChange` gets called with a snapshot of all children each time, not just with the ones that were changed.